Echarts candle sticks are too short
I'm using echarts-for-react to display a candle stick chart and sometimes when the interval is too small. I'm getting candle sticks that are too small. I try to set the yAxis min and max value but it didn't work.
any help?
here's my code
  const option = {
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
      axisPointer: {
        type: "cross",
      },
    },
    axisPointer: {
      link: [{ xAxisIndex: "all" }],
    },
    xAxis: {
      data: state?.times?.map?.(i => new Date(i)).map(a => new Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(a)),
      splitLine: { show: false },
      axisLine: { show: false },
      axisTick: { show: false },
    },
    yAxis: {
      splitLine: {
        show: false,
        min: min || 0,
        max: max || 0,
      },
    },
    grid: {
      left: 0,
    },
    dataZoom: [
      {
        type: "inside",
        minValueSpan: 10,
      },
    ],
    series: [
      {
        type: "candlestick",
        data: state?.prices,
      },
    ],
  };

<EChartsReact
   option={option}
   className="react-charts-custom"
   style={{ height: "600px" }}
/>


Here's some SS


I have difficulties understanding whats the issue. Could you describe more in detail what "candle sticks that are too small" means? It would also be helpful if you could provide a minimal set of data where the issue occurs.

Hi, I'm using binance api to get kline data. By "candle sticks are too small" I mean I the candle are so small that I can't even see it (it's at the top). It would be good if I can make them bigger and move it in the center

nvm.. just now spotted the candles on the second image. Is there a very small value dragging the yAxis so much apart or is echarts forcing 0 to be on the yAxis?

no I log min and max values and they are very close to each other min is around 68k and max is 71k

setting yAxis min to (value) => value.min should work

or setting scale to true

As @Matthais Mertens mentioned in the comments seting scale: true solves the issue
